# Error: File /vercel/path0/node_modules/simple-update-notifier/node_modules/semver/preload.js does not exist

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, vercel

> Deployed Error On Vercel

I tried to deploy Express on Vercel and found the error below. Yesterday, it was still deployed well but it is very strange for today deployment.

> Error: File /vercel/path0/node_modules/simple-update-notifier/node_modules/semver/preload.js does not exist.
> : File /vercel/path0/node_modules/simple-update-notifier/node_modules/semver/preload.js does not exist.

The application is running well without any error. I tried to stop and start it many time and it is no problem on localhost.

Answer (score 0):

1. Try removing node_modules and lock file and then npm i.
2. Check if you have installed bcrypt. Uninstall it and install bcryptjs instead.

This resolved the error for me!